# Default Length for properties of a div tag?

Tags: html, css

What are the default length values for properties (specifically width, height, padding, margin) of a div tag? Is it inherited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `<div>` element, I believe the default value of `width`, `height` is `auto`. And the default value of `padding`, `margin` is `0`. And those rules are not inherited.

Because `<div>` is block level, so by default it occupies the entire width of the container. How is that different from `width: 100%;`? Read on:

[10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth)

> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block